# Replying on my email client (gmail) to a postfix forwarded email replies to my domain address instead of the original sender

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp, dovecot

I've set up postfix with dovecot on my server with the domain "example.com"

Right now if an email is sent to one of my configured (no login) users their emails are shown in the **/var/mail** folder.

Then I modified the "**/etc/postfix/virtual**" to and an entry like this:

```
top@example.com myaddress@gmail.com
```

This had the effect that when an email is sent to top@example.com it is automatically forwarded to my gmail account. And inside the gmail account it is shown as if it was sent from the original user (not my postfix email). But when I click on reply the "To:" address shows "top@example.com" instead of the original user that sent the email to my postfix server.

**How can I fix this? Am I taking the wrong approach?** (like should I be retrieving the emails through pop3 or something?)

---

I've already configured postfix with dovecot so that I can use SMTP with the user name and password. This allows me to send email from my gmail account to other people through my example.com server and when they receive it they will see it as coming from top@example.com.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is caused by sending a test email from an account that Gmail thinks is you. I just ran into the same thing when sending a test email from another Google Apps account of mine (Reply was bringing up my domain email, not the original sender). But when I sent a test email from a newly created Yahoo email account, Gmail's Reply is bringing up the Yahoo account (not my domain email). Looks like Reply All would go to both the Yahoo account (original sender) and my domain email